# How to update values on a row in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I must update a row of a table in an Activity. 
I use a method of my class `DatabaseHelper` that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
Here is the method belonging to the class `DatabaseHelper`:

```
 public void updateQuantitaProdotto(SQLiteDatabase db,String Nome, String Quantita) {
        db.execSQL("update " + ProdottiTable.TABLE_NAME + " set " + ProdottiTable.QUANTITA + "= " + Quantita + "where "
                + "Nome = '" + Nome + "'");

    }
```

I need to pass three parameters but I don't know which value giving as first parameter. 
When I want to create a `SQLiteDatabase` object I get an error on the editor, maybe I can't use it.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              try {
                  if(quantitaSceltaEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()==false) {
                      int quantitaSceltaInt = Integer.parseInt(quantitaSceltaEditText.getText().toString());
                      String prezzoTotale = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", (calcoloPrezzoTotale())));

                      prezzoTotateTextView.setText(prezzoTotale); 
                    var.aggiornaQuantitaProdotto(db,nomeTextView.getText().toString(),String.valueOf(nuovaQuantita));      //which value for db?
                  }
                  else
                      prezzoTotateTextView.setText("0,00");
              }
              catch (Exception e) {};`
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this method is inside your `DatabaseHelper` class, you should not need to pass in `db` from the Activity.

Also, you have a concatenation issue, there should be spaces between `=`, `where`, and `Nome`.

It should be something like this:

```
//Notice no db in the parameters for the method
public void updateQuantitaProdotto(String Nome, String Quantita) {

        //open the database if not done so already            
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //notice the extra spaces below 
        db.execSQL("update " + ProdottiTable.TABLE_NAME + " set " + ProdottiTable.QUANTITA + " = " + Quantita + " where "
                + " Nome = '" + Nome + "'");

        db.close(); //close the db if not needed anymore
    }
```

Call from your Activity without the `db` parameter:

```
//no value for db needed
var.aggiornaQuantitaProdotto(nomeTextView.getText().toString(),String.valueOf(nuovaQuantita));
```

Comment: @Ptr Try the code in the answer, and see if you get an error.